# Generic Delegate and IList<T>

Tags: delegates, ilist

I want to implement a delegate solution for Bubble sort. I have this code:

```
public delegate void SortHandler<T>(IList<T> t);

public static void Sort<T>(IList<T> arr, SortHandler<T> func)
{
func(arr);
}

int[] arr2 = { 10,1,2,3,4 };
CollectionHelper.Sort<int>(arr2, bubble_sort);
```

bubble sort function signature is:

```
static void bubble_sort(int[] array) {}
```

I get this error:

Argument '2': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'DelegatesAndGenerics.SortHandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - your `bubble_sort` method requires an `int[]` as the parameter, whereas `SortHandler` only specifies `IList<T>`. You can't create a `SortHandler<int>` from `bubble_sort`.

Just because you happen to be sorting an `int[]` doesn't mean `CollectionHelper.Sort` is guaranteed to call the delegate with an array instead of (say) a `List<int>`.

For example, consider this implementation:

```
public void Sort<T>(T[] array, SortHandler<T> handler)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>(array);
    handler(list);
}
```

How would you expect that to cope if you'd managed to pass in the `bubble_sort` method as your handler?

The simplest solution is to change your `bubble_sort` method to accept `IList<int>` instead of just `int[]`.

(This is a slightly strange situation though, I have to say. Usually the kind of handler you'd pass into a generic sort method would be something to compare any two elements - not to perform the actual sort itself.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that your `int[]` isn't an IList.  If you change your `SortHandler` delegate like so:

```
public delegate void SortHandler<T>(IEnumerable<T> t);
```

you should be able to use arrays, lists, or whatever you want.

Comment: Doesn't int[] implements the generic interface IList<int>?

Comment: That will have exactly the same problem. `int[]` *does* implement `IList<int>`, but you still can't use a method which will *only* accept an `int[]` for a delegate which is meant to take *any* `IList<int>`.

Comment: When your right, your right.  Teach me to not pay attention.  Can I down-vote myself?